# Accelerometer validation trace

Tags: acceleration, measurements

I am attempting to validate an accelerometer. I have a triaxial accelerometer and placed it on a wheel which goes at various frequencies from 1 to 3 Hz.
Am I right in thinking that I would expect the acceleration in *z* to be 1g?

Then in the *x* and *y* plane I would expect a read out of acceleration in $X(t) = -2\pi fr\cos{(2\pi f t)}$ and acceleration in $Y(t) = -2\pi fr\sin{(2\pi f t)}$ where $r$ is the radius of the wheel and $f$ is frequency.

How can I compare these with my readout from the sensor, and what is the best way to report accuracy? I'm confused as surely I will need to quite accurately time align the two traces.

Comment: Does your wheel fall?

Comment: No its actually a mechanical wheel that sits on a table and I have placed my accelerometer at different positions on it. I have measured the radius to the nearest mm

Comment: Then why do expect an acceleration of $g$ in the $z$-direction?

Comment: I thought for example if the accelerometer was placed on a flat surface it wil always show 1g in the z direction

Comment: This will not happen, because the system is not accelerating. (There is also a normal force).

Comment: Except that it does show 1g when sitting flat.  The accelerometer cannot distinguish between acceleration and sitting still in a gravitational field.  My accelerometer certainly shows ~1g in one direction when sitting still.

Comment: @Bernhard - A basic accelerometer should just measure [proper acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration), which is 1g for something "at rest" in a gravitational field (are you familiar with the [equivalence principle](http://www.einstein-online.info/spotlights/equivalence_principle) in general relativity?)

Comment: @Hypnosifl Useful references, see also Carls comments below. But it basically comes down to whether you take it the acceleration relative to free fall or a coordinate system. I would naturally choose for the latter one for practical purposes on earth.

Comment: @Bernhard - Carl is wrong, see my response. The point I'd make is that a basic accelerometer doesn't "take the acceleration" relative to anything in particular, it just measures proper acceleration directly (a simple method would be springs on different axes with weights on them, then the degree of spring compression/stretching would measure proper acceleration on that axes). I think there are designs that try to filter out gravity, but that's really an "accelerometer + device that tries to determine which direction is pointing towards the Earth at each moment".

Comment: @Hypnosifl Did you consider to add another answer?

Comment: @Bernhard - The focus of this question isn't on *why* an accelerometer should read 1g when at rest on the ground, branny1200 just asked *whether* that was true along with a few other questions--Floris' answer looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Then in the x and y plane I would expect a read out of acceleration in X(t)=−2πfrcos(2πft) and acceleration in Y(t)=−2πfrsin(2πft) where r is the radius of the wheel and f is frequency.

The planes on your accelerometer are aligned with respect to the unit, not with respect to your room.  When you attach it to the wheel, you're going to fix it in place.  So two of the axes will rotate with it.  You would put it on the wheel and align one axis (say x) radially.  Then the entire centripetal acceleration will appear on that axis.  You won't have to worry about any time component.  Your y axis should only show accelerations as you spin up and spin down the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

An accelerometer measures the force on a small test mass and will therefore read 1g total acceleration when at rest on the earth's surface. depending on how well the axes are aligned with the housing and the housing with the vertical, it is quite possible that your device will not have the full value on one axis but that you need to take the vector sum $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

When you have a trace of the response while it's rotating, the trace should have a different magnitude (and a new apparent direction of force) but no sinusoidal variation unless the wheel "wobbles" or unless the accelerometer rotates with respect to the wheel. In the rotating frame of reference of the wheel, the accelerometer is stationary and the apparent acceleration is the (vector) sum of the centrifugal acceleration (observed in rotating frame of reference) and gravitational acceleration.

You said you had obtained traces. Maybe you can show what they looked like?

Comment: Another way of describing the reason for no sinusoidal variation is that the accelerometer is measuring acceleration relative to axes along its own body, not axes in some external inertial frame--so if a particular axis is aligned with the radial direction at one moment, it should continue to be as the wheel rotates, so if the rotation is constant that axis just gives a measure of the constant centripetal acceleration.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - thanks for the comment. That was what I was trying to say; maybe when it is said in two different ways it becomes more obvious to the OP.

Answer (score -1):

As someone in the comments pointed out, it won't show any acceleration in the "z" direction if it's just sitting there. What people mean when they talk about gravitational acceleration is when the object is freely falling.

Your other method with the wheel might be sound, but I'd suggest a better method: since your device definitely doesn't know any "absolute" directions (that is, it's always measured the acceleration in certain directions, no matter how the device is oriented), figure out the directions relative to the device itself, and then drop it off some height, with the device oriented in that direction, so you can measure only that one (for example, have a weight, and then a "tail", like a lawn dart, and put the device on one of the fins of the tail. It will always point in the same direction). This will be a lot simpler than a rotating setup, and allow you to isolate them.

Comment: To clarify (maybe :-) ),  $g$ is a **force** .  Acceleration is a change in velocity which only happens when there's a net force. your accelerometer's net force in the $\hat{z}$ direction is zero due to the normal force of the surface it's sitting on.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you guys for helping me. Well I have considered just a simple drop experiment but the test has already been done by another person and I just must analyse the result

Comment: Hey guys as I have already acquired a trace from this method any ideas of how to work out error? And align the traces so they can be compared?

Comment: @Carl Witthoft - But accelerometers don't measure acceleration relative to a Newtonian inertial frame, nor do they measure net Newtonian "force"--they are real-world devices and hence they are better understood using general relativity which is more accurate than Newtonian gravity. In general relativity, the only frame-invariant notion of acceleration is [proper acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration), and since accelerometers don't make use of any particular reference frame, naturally that's what they measure.

Comment: (continued) According to general relativity, gravity is not really a "force" at all but rather curvature of spacetime, and general relativity's [equivalence principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) says that being in freefall in a gravitational field is locally equivalent to moving inertially (zero proper acceleration) in non-curved spacetime, and likewise sitting at a constant radius in a gravitational field is locally equivalent to accelerating in non-curved spacetime (so that's when an accelerometer should measure a nonzero proper acceleration).

Comment: @Hypnosifl you're going into the ozone there. Accelerometers in everyday use are just strain gauges and there's no need for GR.  RLY!

Comment: @Carl Witthoft - You don't need GR in the design of accelerometers, but that wasn't my point--my point was just the conceptual one that any basic physical device for measuring acceleration like a strain gauge is going to be measuring proper acceleration, not coordinate acceleration in a Newtonian frame. Do you disagree?

Comment: (Of course, you could also use a purely Newtonian analysis to show that simple devices like a strain gauge or a weight on a spring will deviate from their relaxed state when held vertically in a gravitational field--but that's just another way of showing that these devices do *not* measure 'coordinate acceleration in a Newtonian frame', even from a Newtonian perspective)